# divisibility of big powers of 71

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-verification

Since
                  $$ 71 \equiv7\equiv-1 \pmod 8 $$

$\implies71^2 \equiv 1 \pmod 8$

$\implies $ any  power of $71$ would leave either $1$ or $-1$ mod $8$.
Is this logic ok ?

Comment: You are correct

Comment: That's exactly right.

Comment: @J.W.Tanner thank you.

Answer (score 4):

You are correct.  In fact, modulo $8$, any odd number to an odd power is congruent to itself and to an even power is congruent to $1.$

Comment: @David:  are you saying $3^2\equiv1\mod 2^4 ?!$

Comment: no @J.W.Tanner They are saying $$(2k+1)^{2y+1}\equiv (2k+1)\bmod 8\\(2k+1)^{2z}\equiv 1\bmod 8$$

Comment: @RoddyMacPhee:  my comment to David was responding to his comment on my answer (since deleted) claiming that what I said for $8$ holds for $2^n$ in general

Comment: sorry my brain doesn't always work. I thought david was the answerer...

Answer (score 1):

You are absolutelly right. It's good to understand and always keep in mind the basic rules of modular arythmetic, so that you never have doubts about your reasonings. For instance, if:

$$a \equiv b \pmod k$$
$$c \equiv d \pmod k$$

Then

$$ac \equiv bd \pmod k$$

And, as a consequence (set $a=c$, $b=d$ and apply the above equation recursively as many times as needed), for any integer $m$,

$$a^m = b^m$$

You are just applying this property to the case $a=71$, $b=-1$

On a sidenote it's also true that:

$$a+c \equiv b+d \pmod k$$

But, for instance:

$$2^1 \not\equiv 2^5 \mod 4$$

**EXTRA: Elementary proof for that $a \equiv b \pmod{k}$ and $c \equiv d \pmod{k}$ imply $ac \equiv bd \pmod{k}$**:

Let $a$ and $b$ be mod-$k$ congruent. Let also $c$ and $d$ de mod-$k$ congruent. Then

$$a=wk+r_1$$
$$b=xk+r_1$$ 
$$c=yk+r_2$$
$$d=zk+r_2$$

For some integers $w,x,y,z$ and $r_1, r_2 \in \{0,1,...,k-1\}$. Now:

$$ac=wyk^2 + r_1yk + r_2wk + r_1 r_2 = (wyk+r_1y+r_2w)k + r_1 r_2$$
$$bd=xzk^2 + r_1zk + r_2xk + r_1 r_2 = (xzk+r_1z+r_2x)k + r_1 r_2$$

Long story short:

$$ac=sk+r_1 r_2$$
$$bd=tk+r_1 r_2$$

For some integers $s,t$ that we don't even care about. The point is that the remainder after a division by $k$ is in both cases $r_1 r_2$